# IE ng-disabled not working with "as" syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have an issue with ng-disabled it works fine with chrome and firefox but the problem with **IE 11**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>My first app</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as vm">
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.name" />
        <button ng-disabled="vm.isBtnDisabled()">Button</button>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
            app.controller("myController",["$scope", function($scope){
                this.name="";
                this.isBtnDisabled=function(){
                    return this.name.trim().length==0;
                }
            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please let me know if i had made any mistake, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add prototype method `trim` to work with IE11

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
     return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
}
```

```js
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myController",["$scope", function($scope){
   this.name="";
   this.isBtnDisabled=function(){
      return this.name.trim().length==0;
   }
}]);
            
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as vm">
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.name" />
        <button ng-disabled="vm.isBtnDisabled()">Button</button>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: My problem is not about the string, the value i am passing from the controller is not updated in the view

Comment: ie 11 does not support trim function. So you have to manually implement it

Comment: I have just gave trim as an example. it is not because of trim